# SVN trying to commit not-existing file/folder

Tags: svn

I have one txt file (`C:\...folder\test.txt`) by the .svn folder inside another folder. When i make changes inside txt file and trying to commit it shows me

> Error: svn: E200009: Commit failed (details follow):
>
> svn: E200009: 'C:...folder\commit'' is
>   not under version control

I don't have `'commit'` folder(s) or file(s).

Tried already `svn cleanup` and `svn add . --force`. Also tried to delete the  `folder` checkout the txt file back. It didn't help.

Make sure you write `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: please show us your working copy layout, the commands that you run and the result of `svn --version -v`.

Comment: @bahrep there was a problem with quotes